# Have selected rows display at top of screen

Tags: excel, vba

My spreadsheet has a block of data every 19 rows. I would like to write vba so that the user can click a graphic arrow on the side of the block and have the next, or previous, block display at the top of the screen. All I need is the code; linking the graphic is no problem, and I already have an algorithm to determine which of the 30 blocks the user is currently working in.

I have tried many different ways to do this but none seem to do exactly what I had in mind.

Linking the graphic to a cell of the desired block doesn't work because the cell can be left at the bottom of the screen, when I want it to be at the top ready for the user to input data into that block. The solution I am searching for will display the blocks of rows similar to a dashboard. I have googled for days but not found the solution - perhaps I don't know the language to search for.

Any ideas?

Comment: add a screen shot presenting how your sheets really looks like including a kind of shape which one should click. you won't be able to upload a pic here therefore add a link to one uploaded anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the best answer will be: Don't push excel so far to being more than a table calculation progarmm.
But that being said... let's see what we can do.

Bsic idea: literally show only one block and just hide *all* other rows.
Put this in a new module:

```
Public Sub goto_block(n As Long)
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long

    If n < 1 Then Exit Sub
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set ws = Worksheets(1)
    ws.Rows.Hidden = True
    ws.Rows( _
        CStr((n - 1) * 19 + 1) & ":" & CStr((n - 1) * 19 + 19) _
        ).EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    ws.Cells((n - 1) * 19 + 1, "A").Select
End Sub
```

The browsing up and down can be done in plenty of ways.  This one shows how to go up/down by *right-clicking* on the first (topmost visible) cell in Column M/L. (Copy this into the module of the worksheet):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeRightClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim curBlock As Long

    If Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then
        If (Target.Row Mod 19) = 1 Then

            curBlock = Int((Target.Row - 1) / 19) + 1

            If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Columns("M")) Is Nothing Then
                goto_block curBlock + 1
                Cancel = True
                Exit Sub
            ElseIf Not Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Columns("L")) Is Nothing Then
                goto_block curBlock - 1
                Cancel = True
                Exit Sub
            End If

        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Something simple like this wouldn't work to adjust the screen?

Previous 19

```
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-19
```

Next 19

```
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=19
```

Comment: Thanks so much to you two guys for taking the time to help me with my problem. I have been moving house so have only just gotten back into my project.

Answer (score 0):

**Thanks so much to you two guys for taking the time to help me with my problem.** I have been moving house so have only just gotten back into my project.

@MakeCents : Unfortunately I don't know enough about VB yet to know if your suggestion works for my purpose (I programmed Commodore Basic and Assembly Language back in the 80's but the syntax of VB seems to be a different beast).

@KekuSamau : I tried your suggestion and, despite not understanding much about it, it works perfectly.

I am in the process of studying a Wrox book so hope to improve my VB as I go. Thanks again to you both for helping me over this hurdle and keeping my enthusiasm alive.

Daniels